# Scraping multiple webpages and results are being outputted out of order

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I am scraping 3 URLs each of which has multiple pages.  The first 2 links have 2 pages and the 3rd has 3.  Anyways when I scrape them it scrapes page 1 of URL 1 then page 1 of URL 2, instead of page 2 of URL 1.  Then it goes back and scrapes page 2 of URL 1 and page 2 of URL 2 and then scrapes all three pages of URL 3 in order.  So why is it not scraping them al in order, like page 1,2 of URL 1; page 1,2 of URL 2, and then page 1,2,3 of URL 3.  Is there a way to fix it?

SplashSpider.py

```
import csv
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import GameItem

# process the csv file so the url + ip address + useragent pairs are the same as defined in the file
# returns a list of dictionaries, example:
# [ {'url': 'http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Rivals%20of%20Ixalan',
#    'ip': 'http://204.152.114.244:8050',
#    'ua': "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9320; en-GB) AppleWebKit/534.11"},
#    ...
# ]
def process_csv(csv_file):
    data = []
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)
    for fields in reader:
        if fields[0] != "":
            url = fields[0]
        else:
            continue # skip the whole row if the url column is empty
        if fields[1] != "":
            ip = "http://" + fields[1] + ":8050" # adding http and port because this is the needed scheme
        if fields[2] != "":
            useragent = fields[2]
        data.append({"url": url, "ip": ip, "ua": useragent})
    return data


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'splash_spider'  # Name of Spider

    # notice that we don't need to define start_urls
    # just make sure to get all the urls you want to scrape inside start_requests function

    # getting all the url + ip address + useragent pairs then request them
    def start_requests(self):

        # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
        with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
           # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
            requests = process_csv(csv_file)
for req in requests:
            # no need to create custom middlewares
            # just pass useragent using the headers param, and pass proxy using the meta param

            yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                    headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                    splash_url = req["ip"],
                    )

    # Scraping
    def parse(self, response):
        item = GameItem()
        saved_name = ""

        item["Category"] = response.css("span.titletext::text").extract()
        for game in response.css("tr[class^=deckdbbody]"):
            saved_name  = game.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first() or saved_name
            item["card_name"] = saved_name.strip()

            if item["card_name"] != None:
                saved_name = item["card_name"].strip()
            else:
                item["card_name"] = saved_name

            item["Condition"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_7 a::text").get()
            item["stock"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_8::text").extract_first()
            item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9::text").extract_first()

            yield item

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(., "- Next>>")]/@href').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

CSV file where URLs are stored

```
http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Duel%20Decks%20Venser%20vs%20Koth,204.152.114.229,Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9a1) Gecko/20070308 Minefield/3.0a1 
http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Duel%20Decks%20Zendikar%20vs%20Eldrazi,,
http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Duels%20of%20the%20Planeswalkers,,
```

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably due to the use of concurrence.
Try to disable concurrence adding/changing the line below to the settings.py:

```py
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
```

EDIT:
Oh sorry, let's try another thing.
Do you know as the property start_urls works?
It is a special property of the Spider class, you can assign a list of URLs to that and it will run each untill the end.

It will work like that:

```py
class MySpyder(Spyder):
   name = 'MySpyder'
   start_urls = ['url1', 'url2'...]

   def parse(self):
      [do parse stuff]
```

you can read your csv and transform it in a list of urls.

Comment: I tired what you said but it did not fix the problem.  Setting concurrent_requests=1 or just disabling it do not output the data in the right order.  I am still getting page 1 of URL then page 1 of URL 2... instead of all pages of URL 1 then all pages of URL 2

Comment: Sorry for the first awnser, that was a guess. I have edited with another try :)

Comment: So I can set my csv equal to start_urls?  I did not use start_urls since I had stored all of my urls in a csv file.  I needed to store them in that file because there are a lot of them.

Comment: No problem, I already did It. Read the csv, create a list of urla then assign It to stat_urls